# jQuery javascript menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

Does anyone know how you create a menu with this rollover effect. Is it using jQuery? I want to create something similar using WordPress as my CMS. Would be great if there is a WordPress plugin?
http://wptheme5.mipdesign.com/

Thanks for  your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&source=hp&q=jquery+menus&btnG=Google+zoeken&meta=&aq=f&oq=jquery+menus&fp=9f25ce630386be7c

http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&q=jquery+menus+wordpress&meta=&aq=f&oq=&fp=9f25ce630386be7c

And after 2 mins of codebrowsing you should have noticed that the LavaLamp menu is used.

Some info:
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: Hey I'm a designer now a natural coder, but thanks very much :) I've been wondering for ages

Comment: You're welcome! :) Don't forget to accept the answer, so SO remains clean and neat :)